# Chrome Extension with no HTML to directly run JS (display alert with DOM value) after clicking its icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I couldn't find any ready-made solutions, especially with the new Manifest V3 `background` `service-worker` architecture.

I need to create a simple Chrome Extension with no HTML to directly run JS to show an Alert Box with some kind of DOM value (e.g., a DIV's ID) when its icon is clicked. But I'm getting these errors:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Practice",
  "description": "Practice",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "practice.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["practice.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "practice.js" });
});
```

**practice.js**

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
alert(elem ? 'found: ' + elem.id : 'not found');
```

ERROR in background.js:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: alert is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The code you've shown won't even run because there's no chrome.tabs.executeScript in ManifestV3, it's chrome.scripting.executeScript and the syntax is completely different. Also you need either `host_permissions` (for unattended/automatic injection) or `activeTab` permission (injection on click).
2. chrome.tabs.onUpdated is the wrong event, you need chrome.action.onClicked, but in this specific case a better/simpler alternative is to specify "default_popup" in manifest.json and remove the background script.
3. There's no need for `content_scripts` declaration because it injects the specified scripts into each page in each tab every time it's navigated and not on click.

// manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Practice",
  "description": "Practice",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "practice.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"]
}
```

popup.html

```html
<p id=msg></p>
<script src=popup.js></script>
```

popup.js

```js
(async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const [{result, err}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    injectImmediately: true,
    func: id => document.getElementById(id)?.id, // result must be JSON-compatible
    args: ['myDiv'],
  }).catch(err => [{err: err.message}]);
  document.getElementById('msg').textContent = result
    ? 'found: ' + result
    : err || 'not found';
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be the starting point of any modern Chrome extension. Examples like this are very hard to find, for some reason.